# \begin{equarray*} not recognized -- it's in my list of environments

Tags: environments

My Miktex compiler complains that \begin{equarray*} is an undefined. It's in my handy list of Latex commands. Am I out of date or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `eqnarray` (ie, eqNarray, not eqUarray).  But you should really use `align` (from the package `amsmath`) instead of `eqnarray`.  See [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/107497)

Comment: Thanks -- new glasses in my future. I'll switch to align.